# how to set field value for collection type in symfony2

Tags: symfony, formbuilder

//--form timesheettype---it is not entity class

```
class TimeSheetType extends AbstractType {

        public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options) {
            $builder->
                    add('dailyTimeSheet', 'collection', array('type' => new DailyType(), 'allow_add' => true, 'allow_delete' => true, 'prototype' => true,))
                    ->add('comment','textarea');
        }

         public function getName() {
            return 'TimeSheetDaily';
        }

    }
```

//--- DailyType -- there is entity for this type

```
class DailyType extends AbstractType {


    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options) {


        $builder->add('project','entity',array('class'=> 'Parabola\EntityBundle\Entity\Project','property'=>'name'))
               ->add('projectTask', 'entity', array('class'=> 'Parabola\EntityBundle\Entity\ProjectTask','property'=>'name'))
                ->add('hours', 'text');

    }
    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array('data_class' => 'Parabola\EntityBundle\Entity\TimeSheetDaily');
    }

 public function getName() {
    return 'DailySheet';
}
```

//-- controller--

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getRepository('ParabolaEntityBundle:TimeSheetDaily')->findAll();
        $form = $this->createForm(new \Parabola\TimeSheetBundle\Form\TimeSheetType(),$repository);
```

I have entity class TimeSheetDaily. While building form of TimeSheetType, I am passing array of TimeSheetDaily class object to form type. and that TimeSheetType has collection of DailyType. It is not Setting value to the collection field which is nothing but a TimeSheetDaily entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you defined `__constructor` of `TimeSheetDaily` class? 
Do you have something like this?

```
public function __construct(){
//....

$this->dailyTimeSheet = new ArrayCollection();

//....
};
```

It's important to correctly initialize this collection in order for `Symfony` to be able to insert data into it....

Comment: but dailyTimesheet is not a entity class. TimeSheetDaily entity does not have any relation with other entity calss